# What is the name of the minor unit of USDT (Tether)?

Tags: usdt, tether

Is there a name given to the smallest unit of USDT or Tether? For example:

- 1 Bitcoin = 100000000 satoshi
- 1 Ether = 1000000000000000000 wei
- 1 USDT = 1000000 ??

If there is no such name, I would accept this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is cents, as in the US dollar.

0.10 USDT is 10 cents.

Comment: What is 0.001 USDT equal to? There is no name for this unit in USD. Similarly what is the name of the unit equal to 0.00001 USDT i.e. the smallest possible amount of USDT?

Comment: There does not need to be a name for units. They can just follow the normal SI cents, millis and micros convention if you want to call them for something. USDT has 6 decimal places https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7